# Python matplotlib: How to tick and ticklabel an axis/object independently of the object's scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale, legend, colorbar

The following code defines a rectangular region in a figure and draws a color bar based on a color map in it. I've changed the color bar's scaling to the cubic root of its original, but I wish the ticks and ticklabels to remain linear across the bar length, so it will be correct for my purpose. I might as well draw a straight line there and graduate it linearly across if possible. How can I approach this? mpl is matplotlib and plt its pyplot. The idea is to make a color bar legend for a choropleth, a colored world map.

```
def draw_legend (clr_map):
    """ Draw color bar legend ... (inspired by: http://ramiro.org/notebook/basemap-choropleth/) """
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,12))
    ax_legend = fig.add_axes([0.26, -0.02, 0.48, 0.016], zorder=3)
    grads = np.linspace(0.,1.,400)
    bins = np.linspace(0.,1.,10)
    scheme = [clr_map(i/400) for i in range(400)]
    cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(scheme)
    cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax_legend, cmap=cmap, ticks=bins, boundaries=grads**(1/3.), \
                               orientation='horizontal')   # Before I'd done cmap as sqrt(): boundaries=np.sqrt(grads)
    #cb.ax.set_xticks(bins)
    cb.ax.set_xticklabels([str(round(i, 1)) for i in bins], fontsize=10);

draw_legend (plt.cm.plasma)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting the ticks on a colorbar you can use `cb.set_ticks(bins**(1/3.))`. You could also just scale the colormap directly (`clr_map((i/400.)**(1./3))`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.colorbar
import numpy as np

def draw_legend (clr_map):
    """ Draw a color bar legend 
        with a qubic root colormap
    """
    # Version 1, scale boundaries, set ticks to colorbar values
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
    ax_legend = fig.add_axes([0.26, 0.7, 0.48, 0.1], zorder=3)
    ax_legend.set_title("Version 1\nscale boundaries, set ticks to colorbar values")
    grads = np.linspace(0.,1.,400)
    bins = np.linspace(0.,1.,11)
    scheme = [clr_map(i/400.) for i in range(400)]
    cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(scheme)
    cb = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax_legend, cmap=cmap, ticks=bins, boundaries=grads**(1/3.), \
                               orientation='horizontal')   

    cb.set_ticks(bins**(1/3.))
    cb.ax.set_xticklabels(bins**(1/3.), fontsize=10, rotation =45, ha="center")
    cb.draw_all()

    # Version 2, scale colormap, set ticks to arbitrary values
    ax_legend2 = fig.add_axes([0.26, 0.27, 0.48, 0.1], zorder=3)
    ax_legend2.set_title("Version 2\nscale colormap, set ticks to arbitrary values")
    grads = np.linspace(0.,1.,400)
    bins = np.linspace(0.,1.,11)
    scheme = [clr_map((i/400.)**(1./3)) for i in range(400)]
    cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(scheme)
    cb = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax_legend2, cmap=cmap, ticks=bins, 
                               orientation='horizontal')   
    cb.set_ticks(bins)
    cb.draw_all()


draw_legend (plt.cm.jet)
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The tick placement is linear in your result, but I want the labels too to read 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0, thus have the ticks totally independent in scale of the color bar transformation

Comment: That was completely unclear from the question. I edited the answer to include both solutions.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the complete answer with additional style corrections. It's the right solution. Once I'm able to vote, I'll vote up your answer.